# pseudo columns & DUAL table - what do they actually mean?

Tags: sql, oracle, dual-table

Dual table is used to select pseudo columns.
it has one row and one column DUMMY which has a value X.

I have two questions

1. What actually does a pseudo
   column mean?
2. How is the dual able to give the
   value for example:

   ```
   select sysdate from dual
   ```

   will result in current datetime.  How is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pseudo-column is a function which returns a system generated value.  `sysdate` is a function which returns the current datetime; `rownum` is a pseudo-column that returns the row number in a result set.

The nomenclature dates from the earlier days of Oracle, before we had PL/SQL.  It just means that we can use these functions in the projection of a SELECT statement, just like the columns of a table.  Nowadays we can write our own functions and use them in SQL statements without blinking, and so the phrase "pseudo-column" is a tad confusing.

The feature which distinguishes a function from a pseudo-column is that the pseudo-column *returns a different value for each row in the resultset* whereas a function returns the same value (unless some column in the table is passed as a parameter to derive the value).

Dual is another venerable slice of Oracle history.  It is a table which contains one row, and *which the database knows contains one row*.  So the select statement you quote is just saying "give me the current datetime".  It is functionally equivalent to

```
select sysdate 
from emp
where rownum = 1
/
```

In PL/SQL the select from dual is nugatory.  We can just code this:

```
l_date := sysdate;
```

One common use for DUAL used to be getting the next value of a sequence in a trigger.  Since 11g we can do ...

```
:new.id := my_seq.nextval;
```

Under the covers this still executes `select my_seq.nextval into :new.id from dual;`

Comment: functionally equivalent - unless `emp` is empty :)

Answer (score 1):

### 2. How does selecting from DUAL give the system time?

SQL has a number of built-in functions which don't need parentheses after them to invoke them.  One such function in Oracle is SYSDATE.

Remember, if you have a table, a SELECT statement with no restriction condition (WHERE clause) normally returns one row of data for each row in the table.  So, given a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Ex1(Dummy CHAR(10) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Ex1 VALUES('Abacus');
INSERT INTO Ex1 VALUES('Sedentary');
INSERT INTO Ex1 VALUES('Caucasus');
```

Running the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT Dummy FROM Ex1;
```

will return 3 rows.  Now, suppose I write the statement as:

```
SELECT 'ABC', Dummy, SYSDATE FROM Ex1;
```

This will also return 3 rows:

- ABC, Abacus, 2010-03-03
- ABC, Sedentary, 2010-03-03
- ABC, Caucasus, 2010-03-03

If I omit the Dummy column:

```
SELECT 'ABC', SYSDATE FROM Ex1;
```

I get:

- ABC, 2010-03-03
- ABC, 2010-03-03
- ABC, 2010-03-03

And if I omit the string literal:

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM Ex1;
```

I get:

- 2010-03-03
- 2010-03-03
- 2010-03-03

And I delete two rows and rerun the query, I get:

```
DELETE FROM Ex1 WHERE Dummy > 'B';
SELECT SYSDATE FROM Ex1;
```

I get:

- 2010-03-03

Because there's just the one row of data in the table Ex1.

Nominally, I could do:

```
 UPDATE Ex1 SET Dummy = 'X';
 RENAME TABLE Ex1 AS Dual;
```

Of course, you can't do that - I'm not sure whether Oracle supports a RENAME TABLE statement and it probably wouldn't let you rename your table so it could be confused with the built-in DUAL table.  But conceptually, the table Ex1 with a single row in it is isomorphic with DUAL.

### 1. What is a Pseudo-Column?

Unless Oracle has a specific special meaning for the term, then a pseudo-column is a column that appears to be part of the table but that is not actually stored as data in the table.  A classic example is a row number:

```
SELECT ROWNUM, * FROM SomeTable
```

The output appears to have a column ROWNUM (ROWID in Informix, with which I'm most familiar) but that is not directly stored in the DBMS.  Different DBMS have other different pseudo-columns, for different purposes.

It is sometimes difficult to distinguish between a pseudo-column and a function.

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo-column is an Oracle assigned value (pseudo-field) but not stored on disk.

Pseudocolumns are not actual columns in a table but they behave like columns.

For example, you can select values from a pseudocolumn. However, you cannot insert into, update, or delete from a pseudocolumn. Also note that pseudocolumns are allowed in SQL statements, but not in procedural statements.

NOTE:- pseudocolumns are allowed in SQL statements, but not in procedural statements.

SQL> SELECT sysdate, systimestamp FROM dual;
SYSDATE   SYSTIMESTAMP

---

13-DEC-07 13-DEC-07 10.02.31.956842 AM +02:00

Answer (score 0):

pseudo Columns : ROWID , ROWNUM , LEVEL

Comment: A pseudo-column is an Oracle assigned value (pseudo-field) but not stored on disk. Pseudocolumns are not actual columns in a 
table but they behave like columns.

pseudo Columns : ROWID , ROWNUM , LEVEL , COLUMN_VALUE